# Running CrateDB in production

Tags: windows, cratedb

As suggested by https://crate.io/docs/crate/guide/en/latest/deployment/cloud/aws/ec2-setup.html. I've been trying to setup a CrateDb (3.0.2) cluster. However setting `network.host: _site_` prevents the node from starting. Setting everything back to default settings of course starts the instance but this is bound to `localhost`.

All I'm trying to do is to evaluate and set up CrateDB cluster. Sadly the error received isn't useful as it seems to complain about heap size (on a fresh Windows install with 8GB ram and empty database). Does anyone know how to set up a production instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you installing it on amazon web services or on windows? the documentation above is for AWS. here's the correct documentation: https://crate.io/docs/crate/guide/en/latest/scaling/multi-node-setup.html

Comment: Using Windows machine on AWS. The problem is I can't seem to be able to expose a single machine with the config suggested.

Comment: yes, first try to expose a single machine. depending on the type of address your node has locally (private 10.x, 172.16.x, 192.168.x or public), choose _site - or _global. when exposing crate you also need to set CRATE_HEAP_SIZE. after that try to access crate not via localhost, but the ip of the machine (ipconfig /all)

Comment: They're the settings that don't work. I'll try again with heap size setting explicitly set. I have tried both on windows and Linux in case there were any differences in how networking is done