# Query Crate Database by SQLAlchemy Dialect: No more Servers available

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, cratedb

I'd like to give it a try with crate. I first tried it by loading some twitter data and query from admin UI successfully. However, when I tried to make a query with SQLAlchemy, I've got the following error.

```py
OperationalError: (crate.client.exceptions.ConnectionError) 
No more Servers available, exception from last server: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4200): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/_sql (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f51485b2c18>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

```
[SQL: SELECT * FROM tweets LIMIT 100; ]

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

This is the code I ran that caused the error.

```
from crate import client
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

engine = sa.create_engine('crate://localhost:4200')
query = (
            "SELECT * "
            "FROM tweets "
            "LIMIT 100; "
    )
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Any idea how to fix it (the settings are all default)?

---

**Update:**

Crate is running on host system while  Jupyter is running in a container on the same machine. 
I can access Crate via "http://localhost:4200" on the host machine but can't do "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4200" from other machine in the same natwork.

I tried both:

```
engine = sa.create_engine('crate://10.7.116.222:4200')
engine = sa.create_engine('crate://')
```

which caused the same error:

```
Removed server http://127.0.0.1:4200 from active pool
Removed server http://127.0.0.1:4200 from active pool
```

```py
OperationalError: (crate.client.exceptions.ConnectionError) 
No more Servers available, exception from last server: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4200): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/_sql (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5147faaa58>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[SQL: SELECT * FROM tweets LIMIT 10; ]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but according to the [documentation](https://crate.io/docs/clients/python/en/latest/sqlalchemy.html#create-an-engine) 'localhost:4200' is assumed so you could connect using just `engine = sa.create_engine('crate://')`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, it didn't work. I've added some info to the question as well.

Comment: oh so are you saying you can't access crate from inside the container?

Comment: No I cannot access crate from inside the container.

Comment: well that makes sense, since crate would be bound on local port and your jupyter  notebook cant see it. try exposing crate on a public interface

Comment: Anywhere that I can find more information about that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883996/running-cratedb-in-production buried in the comments